# Sitecore IP Geolocation - CM /CD

Tags: content-delivery, geo-location

I am new to Sitecore and I need help with Geolocation service.
We have a website build over Sitecore with CM and CD servers deployed on Azure.
We activated IP Geolocation service on CM and its working fine.

How i can check it on CD?

Do I need to apply it again on CD or just need some DB configuration?

**UPDATE -** We verified that this service is activated based on licence so wherever the license is used then the service will be active. 
Now our problem with this service on CD is in the Application Gateway on Azure which is not forwarding the user Visit information correctly.

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are on? Are you using MongoDB as Experience Database?

Comment: Make sure you copy all the dlls and App_config/CES folder in your delivery servers.

Comment: Is it the full answer or only a comment describing one of the things which need to be done?

Comment: sitecore XP8.2 , and until now there is no Ex. database, they are using sitecore as CMS only mode.

Comment: You have fixed you first problem. I think that this question should be then answered. Your updated question seems to me not related to Sitecore and therefore maybe you should use different StackExchange network not Sitecore...

Comment: I'm just updating the question as reference for the users ,i'm not waiting any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We verified that this service is activated based on licence so wherever the license is used then the service will be active.

Answer (score 0):

From memory the Geolocation service is activated against your license key, so you don't need to do anything differently on your CD / CM server.  The only thing to double check is that the `Analytics.PerformLookup` setting is set to `true` on each server.  The documentation says it should only be true on one server, but in my experience that's not correct.

Comment: i checked it and its true on both servers

Comment: Ah okay.  And silly question, but the license key is also the same on both servers?